# Почему «уходовая косметика» — некорректное выражение?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, точное-словоупотребление

Что не так с этим выражением? Почему корректно *средства для ухода*, но не *уходовая косметика*?

Comment: Моя мама занималась всю жизнь редактурой. Я сам далек от этого, но слово резало мне слух, хотя меня убеждали что все с ним в порядке. А почему я сказать не могу, видимо что-то передается на генетическом уровне)))

Answer (score 3):

Потому что слова "уходовый" нет ни в одном из авторитетных (книжных) толковых словарей русского языка. Его также нет и в орфографическом словаре.

На мой взгляд, это слово звучит некрасиво (режет слух). Взяли существительное и переделали его в прилагательное.

Answer (score 3):

1. **Уходовая или ухаживающая косметика?**

Занимательный курьёз. Слово «уходовый» в литературном русском языке отсутствует, мы его не найдём ни в одном словаре.

То ли они отстают от речевой практики, то ли ещё какая-то причина.
Выражение «уходовая косметика» или ещё более странное «ухаживающая косметика» употребляется в интернете уже более 10 лет. Ещё с конца нулевых на форумах велись споры, как называть не декоративную, а гигиеническую косметику. Выходит, какие-то «уходовые средства» без рода и племени давно ходят по интернету.
Оказывается, **русский язык до сих пор не породил адекватного прилагательного от существительного «уход»!** Вот такой лингвистический курьёз.

https://yandex.ru/q/article/ukhodovaia_ili_ukha_47f36047/?utm_source=yandex

2. В чем курьез? Все в этом слове **нехорошо** – и фонетика, и семантика. Ассоциации с глаголом не самые приятные: то ли провожают кого, то ли "уходИть" хотят до неузнаваемости. А существительное на технический термин похоже. Даже предметы ухода за больными  и те "уходовыми" не называются, а здесь речь идет об особой красоте прекрасного пола.
3. **Грамота**

[http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=уходов](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Вопрос № 283238

Здравствуйте! Допустимо ли употребление словосочетания **"уходовая косметика"** в статье о косметике по уходу за кожей лица и тела? Спасибо!

Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Такое употребление некорректно. Лучше написать: **средства для ухода**...

4. Косметика ***гигиеническая, заботливая, аккуратная, бережная, внимательная…***

Ничего не подходит?

Предлагаю назвать **КR-косметикс (care cosmetics).**

Бренд оставляю за собой.

Comment: Ухаживающая косметика тоже не подойдёт? По аналогии: средства для мытья ч.-н. — моющие средства.

Comment: Это слово в основном и используется, но оно тоже неидеально - длинное, неудобное в произношении. К тому же словарями оно тоже не нормируется, как и слово "уходовый"

Comment: *«Ещё с конца нулевых на форумах велись споры, как называть не декоративную, а гигиеническую косметику»* На мой взгляд она уже имеет название «гигиеническая косметика», и не нужно искать, как называть то, что и так уже имеет название. (моя критика адресована не к вам, а к тем, кто ищет)

Answer (score 2):

Если исходит из определения в словаре, которое приведено ниже, косметика — это и есть средства по уходу за телом:

> **КОСМЕ́ТИКА**, -и, ж.
>
> 1. Уход за лицом и телом с гигиенической целью и для придания им большей привлекательности, свежести.
>
>    ```
>    Лечебная косметика. Кабинет косметики. [Ознобишин] пошучивал насчет того, что узнал секреты Лизиной косметики. Федин, Необыкновенное лето.
>    ```
>
> *[Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]*

Поэтому «уходовая косметика» может быть разновидностью тавтологии:

> **ТАВТОЛОГИЯ** ...
>
> 3. Неоправданная избыточность выражения.
>
>    ```
>    Более лучшее положение (в форме лучшее уже заключено значение сравнительной степени). Самые высочайшие вершины (в форме высочайшие уже заключено значение превосходной степени).
>    ```
>
> *[[Розенталь Д.Э. «Словарь лингвистических терминов»](https://gufo.me/dict/linguistics_rosenthal/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F)]*

---

В первом определении сказано: *«Уход за лицом и телом с **гигиенической целью** и для придания им большей привлекательности, свежести»*.

Та косметика, о которой вы хотите сказать, применяется прежде всего с **гигиенической целью** и называется **гигиенической косметикой**.

> К **гигиенической косметике** относятся косметические кремы, эмульсии,
> гели, желе, масла для ухода за кожей лица, рук, тела, ног, для бритья
> и после бритья, лосьоны различные, туалетное мыло, шампуни и прочие
> средства для ухода за волосами, зубные пасты, пеномоющие средства для
> ванн и др.
>
> *[[znaytovar.ru](https://znaytovar.ru/s/Gigienicheskaya-kosmetika.html)]*

Название «уходовая косметика», скорей всего, является маркетинговым ходом, а само слово «уходовая», скорей всего, возникло под влиянием английского слова «care».

Дело в том что слово «уход» имеет позитивную коннотацию: «забота»; а слово «гигиена» стало ошибочно ассоциироваться только с чистотой.

Вот и стали, вероятно, использовать словосочетание «уходовая косметика», потому что оно более «продаваемое».

На самом деле:

> **ГИГИЕ́НА**, -ы, ж. Наука, изучающая влияние различных факторов внешней среды на организм человека и разрабатывающая меры сохранения здоровья. *Правила гигиены.*
>
> Оттенок значения: **Совокупность практических мер, обеспечивающих сохранение здоровья.** *Гигиена жилищ. Гигиена труда. Личная гигиена.*
>
> [От греч. ‛υγιαίνω — я здоров]
>
> *[Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]*

Поэтому косметику, направленную на обеспечение сохранения здоровья кожи, волос, ногтей и т. д., совершенно правильно называть гигиенической.

Comment: Интересно. Задумалась, что, например, помаду привыкли называть гигиенической, это выражение прижилось даже в рекламе. А с косметикой так почему-то не сработало

Answer (score 1):

Второй ответ

1. У нас в языке существуют такие слова, как **VIP-вклад, VIP-отель, VIP-процедура.** VIP в современном понимании – это особое обслуживание высокого качества (для особо важных персон). Графика этих слов не вызывает никаких нареканий.
2. А если написать так: **CARE-косметика, VIP-косметика.**

И действительно, кто может быть **более важен для вас, чем вы сами?**  Какой эгоизм, скажете вы!  Это шутка, конечно, но мне запомнилось мнение одного молодого врача: "Вы должны любить и беречь себя так, как будто вы – это драгоценная ваза". Да и в любом случае при таком подходе к своему здоровью вы и для своих близких не будете создавать лишних проблем, а это уже не эгоизм, а забота о них, о любимых. **Поэтому решено: вы – это VIP** (Very Important Person).

3. Ввиду всего сказанного косметике по уходу требуется  **новое название**. Здесь надо проявить фантазию, нестандартный подход, а наши мысли не идут дальше привычных сочетаний: моющие средства, ухаживающая косметика и т.д.

Даже если по существу это  та же **гигиеническая** косметика, противопоставленная **декоративной**, но название **должно быть другим** – ярким, привлекательным, сияющим новизной.

Потому что время сейчас другое, а слово "гигиена" кажется нам **морально устаревшим.**

Answer (score 0):

Бренд оставь за собой, умник, KR не приживется )) А выражение "уходовая" живее всех живых ) придумано в народе, так как существует еще и декоративная косметика, целью которой является как раз не только гигиенический уход за кожей или волосами.

Answer (score 0):

Уходовая – словесный уродец, для торговок вполне. Но здесь речь изначально о грамотном языке, а не о языке челноков и продавцов цыганской косметики)

Comment: Посмотрите статистику запросов в гугле по «уходовой косметике». Явно не торговки столько пишут. Очень странно и непрофессионально, говоря о грамотной речи, мыслить такими категориями.